# nsdate from csv dump of old database

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an old file from a home made app from 2013 - sql lite

I'd like to resurrect the data but as the old Xcode project is old I am recreating a new app with less functions as they are no longer needed.

I can open the old sql lite database and export the tables as cvs files, that I'm trying to import into the new app.

Generally working however I am stuck with the date information. In the old app this was an NSDate and in the new app it is also an NSDate. In the csv file it is just a string - an example would be

371401200

I can't work out how to add this as a date because it's not a 'normal' date string so the date from string don't work correctly.

How can I bring in this data?

(hobbyist coder working on app for home use only)

Comment: Maybe this is a timestamp similar to unix timestamps? (e.g. seconds since 1970-01-01). Converting it from epoch yields a date in 1981 … could this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is most likely a UNIX timestamp (starting at 1 January 1970) .

You can get an `NSDate` from the string with

```
NSString *timeString = @"371401200";
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = timeString.doubleValue;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];

NSLog(@"%@", date); // 1981-10-08 15:00:00 +0000
```

or maybe it's based on Apple's *reference date* (starting at 1 January 2001)

```
NSString *timeString = @"371401200";
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = timeString.doubleValue;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timeStamp];

NSLog(@"%@", date); // 2012-10-08 15:00:00 +0000
```